# How can I Change the default scale and precision of decimals in Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

In the application I'm building, I have many decimal fields with a specific precision and scale that need to be mapped from a database.  I can achieve this by using the `Precision()` and `Scale()` methods:

```
public class ClassAMap : ClassMap<ClassA>
{
    public ClassAMap ()
    {
        Map(x => x.Value).Precision(22).Scale(12);
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change the default precision and scale for decimals, so I don't need to remember to add the calls to `Precision()` and `Scale()` for every decimal mapped?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can define a PropertyConvention. Following is the general idea. (NOT tested)

```
public class DecimalConvention : IPropertyConvention
    {
        public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
        {
            if (instance.Type == typeof(decimal) || instance.Name == "Value") //Set the condition based on your needs
            {
               instance.Precision(22).Scale(12);    
            }
        }
    }
```

Make sure you include this convention when Fluent is configured.

Comment: how can I alter existing column to new decimal precision and scale? this solution not worked for me