# Nhibernate: Save all decimal properties with only two decimal numbers

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to tell nhibernate to save all the numeric properties with only two decimals? I'm using fluent nhibernate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @gsco's answer if you need to apply this across classes for all numeric properties, you can define a [PropertyConvention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426496/how-can-i-change-the-default-scale-and-precision-of-decimals-in-fluent-nhibernate/5426714#5426714) and specify the override.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something similar to this in your mapping.

```
Map(x => x.Amount).Precision(8).Scale(2);
```